# How to get mean of one column depends on other column category

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, mean, boxplot

I'm new to DataScient and I'm having difficulties.
I am having one dataset which is as follow :

```
ApplicantIncome Education
5000            Graduate
6000            Non-Graduate
7000            Graduate
2000            Non-Graduate
```

I want to get mean value of ApplicantIncome grouped by Education Catergory.

Like :

Mean :

```
ApplicationIncome :
Graduate : 6000
Non-Graduate : 4000
```

Also,by seeing the boxplot can we find mean ?

Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby('Education').mean()`

Comment: thanks, it was so simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @[YO_Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9177877/yo-chris) answer is :

df.groupby('Education').mean()